# Unable to Configure EntityManagerFactory - JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, gwt, jpa, openshift

I have an application developed in GWT + Errai using Postgres as backend, deployed in jboss7.
I have recently migrated the whole application from one Openshift (Origin) instance to another with rhc client. And then manually restored the dump of database with sftp. The application migrated successfully, But I m unable to login to my application .

I ve tailed the logs on server and It gives me following Exception.

```
    org.jboss.errai.bus.client.api.base.MessageDeliveryFailure: error invoking endpoint
at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.AbstractRPCMethodCallback.invokeMethodFromMessage(AbstractRPCMethodCallback.java:61)
at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.ValueReplyRPCEndpointCallback.callback(ValueReplyRPCEndpointCallback.java:22)
at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.RemoteServiceCallback.callback(RemoteServiceCallback.java:54)
at org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints$2.callback(CDIExtensionPoints.java:494)
at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.DeliveryPlan.deliver(DeliveryPlan.java:47)
at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.ServerMessageBusImpl.sendGlobal(ServerMessageBusImpl.java:293)
at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.SimpleDispatcher.dispatchGlobal(SimpleDispatcher.java:46)
at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.service.ErraiServiceImpl.store(ErraiServiceImpl.java:97)
at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.service.ErraiServiceImpl.store(ErraiServiceImpl.java:114)
at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.servlet.DefaultBlockingServlet.doPost(DefaultBlockingServlet.java:140)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
at org.jboss.web.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:466)
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:400)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No SchemaFactory that implements the schema language specified by: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema could be loaded
at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newInstance(SchemaFactory.java:204)
at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.loadURL(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:91)
at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.deploy(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:171)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:324)
 81 more
*** Message delivery failure ***
 Bus: org.jboss.errai.bus.server.ServerMessageBusImpl@20e1bbe6
 Message: CommandType=getStrategyForUser:com.magick.models.shared.User:, ErrorTo=app.client.shared.service.StrategyService:RPC.getStrategyForUser:com.magick.models.shared.User::4:Errors:RPC, ReplyTo=app.client.shared.service.StrategyService:RPC.getStrategyForUser:com.magick.models.shared.User::4:RespondTo:RPC, ToSubject=app.client.shared.service.StrategyService:RPC, MethodParms=[null]
errorMessage: Error calling remote service: app.client.shared.service.StrategyService:RPC
exception: org.jboss.errai.bus.client.api.base.MessageDeliveryFailure: error invoking endpoint
disconnect: false
```

**Updated more info :**

we have tried the following things on new Openshift instance

- Creating a new OpenShift application
- Cloning an identical instance

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="pu-magick" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> <!-- TODO: JTA -->
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

     <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/magick</jta-data-source>

      <class>com.magick.models.shared.User</class>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" /> 
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I m using JPA as data access layer. Any idea about this ?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like a problem with the persistence.xml

Comment: HI Jens, well ... the same application is running on another openshift instance and Its running absolutely fine.